# Color line in scene kit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am using the following code to draw a line between two nodes:

```
class func lineBetweenNodeA(nodeA: SCNNode, nodeB: SCNNode) -> SCNNode {
    let positions: [Float32] = [nodeA.position.x, nodeA.position.y, nodeA.position.z, nodeB.position.x, nodeB.position.y, nodeB.position.z]
    let positionData = NSData(bytes: positions, length: sizeof(Float32)*positions.count)
    let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]
    let indexData = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(Int32) * indices.count)
    let source = SCNGeometrySource(data: positionData, semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex, vectorCount: indices.count, floatComponents: true, componentsPerVector: 3, bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float32), dataOffset: 0, dataStride: sizeof(Float32) * 3)
    let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.Line, primitiveCount: indices.count, bytesPerIndex: sizeof(Int32))
    let line = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    line.firstMaterial?.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelConstant
    line.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIColor.orangeColor()
    return SCNNode(geometry: line)
}
```

I want to be able to pass in a color when I call this function so that it changes color accordingly...

How can I specify the color for the line drawn?

I edited the code to what works for me. I used the emission property instead of diffuse and I used constant light...

Comment: Haven't you already specified a color? I see something about an `orangeColor` in the code you posted.

Comment: It doesn't look like it works. The line is always black

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a material's `lightingModelName` defaults to `SCNLightingModelBlinn`. With this lighting model the diffuse material property is used as follows:

```
color = ... + diffuse * max(0, dot(N, L)) + ...
```

but since your geometry does not have normals, `diffuse` is always multiplied by 0.

You might want to use the `SCNLightingModelConstant` lighting model or use the `emission` material property instead of `diffuse`.

Comment: I tried to use the emission property instead of diffuse but it's still black.

Comment: ok so I think that using light constant works, though it's hard to see the color of the line because it's real thin... I did this: line.firstMaterial?.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelConstant